# Alert Dialogue not showing

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

Other code is working but alert dialogue is not showing.

Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                confirm.setTitle("Do you confirm this order?");
                confirm.setMessage(order);
                confirm.setCancelable(true);
                confirm.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        orderId ++;
                        orderConfirmed = order;
                        order = "";
                    }
                });
```

Comment: you need to add  confirm.show();

Comment: confirm.show().

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.show()` behind confirm.

Answer (score 0):

One important call is missing, do - `confirm.show()`

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

confirm.setTitle("Do you confirm this order?");
confirm.setMessage(order);
confirm.setCancelable(true);

confirm.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        orderId ++;
        orderConfirmed = order;
        order = "";
     }
  });
AlertDialog.show();
```

hope this may help you